# Is there a material that can harden when blunt force is applied, but also be lightweight?

Tags: materials, clothing

So, in the future year of 2569, technology has progressed greatly from what it was in the 21st century. The people on earth don't have to worry about food or resources, as 3D printers can take care of all your needs. The total human population across the galaxy about is 178 billion, but people only have to live in crowded conditions if they want to, as there are over 10,000 planets for you to live on. Robots take care of the sick, and humans are only in hospitals for the need ms of emotional support.

Clothing technology has also advanced. Since people in the 26th century live busy lives, they don’t want to be stopped by trivial matters like broken bones. Clothing manufacturers have come up with an #X material that is lightweight when worn, but can harden and form an adequate cast around a person's arm. My question is, is there a real-life material that can be lightweight one second, but harden from a blunt impact also?

Comment: So far in the future, why would you care about material existing now? Also, you should care how you write. That said, @dot_Sp0T, mistakes like that are not highlighted by spellchecker, and hard to spot. Unless OP has history of ignoring spelling advice, please, more patience.

Comment: The main problem with this is that you can have something that's lightweight and hard: they're not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @JacaScriptCoder: You misunderstood the question. It doesn’t have to be both hard and lightweight at the same time, it just has to have the ability to become harder when blunt force is applied to it

Comment: you may want to look into carbon nanotubes

Comment: Something like [this](https://vimeo.com/61022148)?

Comment: @Genry Taylor: Yeah

Comment: Non-newtonian fluids (preferably not water-based) and things like diameme (https://www.google.nl/amp/s/www.graphene-info.com/new-graphene-material-called-diamene-switches-flexible-harder-diamond-upon-impact%3famp)

Comment: I don't see how any of the setting is relevant to the question (or worldbuilding in general), nor do I see how this question is relevant to worldbuilding at all.

Comment: @DT Cooper If its lightweight at any point, its going to be lightweight when it gets hard too.

Comment: @Aify we answer questions about armor all the time.  Other than being a real-world question, which the moderators have declared ***on-topic,*** what's your beef?

Comment: @JBH My beef is that the question can be completely stripped down to "is there a real-life material that hardens from a blunt impact" - which obviously exists. If this question was asked on its own without the unrelated flavor text, it would quickly be closed as nothing to do with worldbuilding. My secondary beef is that the question shows no research effort whatsoever, but that's not grounds for closure, unfortunately - at least not without a "no prior research" close reason.

Comment: @Aify, The moderators need to make their final ruling.  They've declared questions like these on-topic.  There is no bulletted item in the [help] that it violates, and personal opinions about what is or is not worldbuilding are unacceptable.  That the user didn't perform prior research is reprensible and deserves downvoting.  But when the [help] states that worldbuilding applies to the smallest hamlets and the largest multiverse, you need to be more convincing as to why it's not worldbuilding.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a thin sheet of [hardened steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardened_steel) satisfies the requirements. It is lightweight, the thinner the lighter. It is hard. The question does not say that the material needs to be soft and flexible before the impact. The question does not say that the material must be strong. BTW, casts are usually made of [plaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaster), which is a very very soft material.

Comment: Just a point of clarification the moderators didn't declare anything.  We collected historic data and past conversation on the topic and presented it to the community for review.  If I were allowed to declare things unilaterally we wouldn't do physics questions because they give me a headache.

Comment: Have you considered a thin membrane filled with something like [oobleck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid#Oobleck), or something with similar properties? Like a non-newtonian solid?

Comment: Cornstarch, perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps [auxetic marials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxetics) would fit the bill?  Auxetics are materials that grow **thicker** when stretched and have already been researched for use as [body armor](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-665X/aaa3cf) and there's actually a commercial product, Zetix, used for [bomb proofing](https://gizmodo.com/330343/zetix-blast-proof-fabric-resists-multiple-car-bombs-makes-our-heads-explode).

Auxetics don't harden after being stretched but perhaps you can add a technological development whereby when the material is stretched, small vessels throughout the material rupture, react with oxygen to form a voluminous foam, fill the cells of the now stretched auxetic material, and then solidify.  The lightweight fabric is now a rigid cast.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.se, Alex

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding, Alex! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

The material you are looking for is called diamene, it consist of two layers of graphene on top of each other. Normally it is very flexible but when pressure is applied it becomes stiffer than diamond, and it’s extremely light weight.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.graphene-info.com/new-graphene-material-called-diamene-switches-flexible-harder-diamond-upon-impact%3famp